# How to stop a username from having html in it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a website that has a sign up form. In the sign up form I noticed that the user can enter in html like:

```
<div style = 'color:red;font-size:30px;'>Bob</div>
```

I know that I can use `htmlspecialchars()` but it keeps the html in the string when it is inserted into the database. So my question is:

Can I detect if there is any html in the string and then ,if there is, ask them to enter in a new username?

I'm looking to do this in either PHPor JavaScript.

Comment: You are asking how to filter input. Often, another option is to encode output (though it may not apply here). Jim Manico (Web Security ninja at OWASP) recommends output encoding rather than input filtering. That's because an attacker can often side step filtering and blacklists. But the attacker can't control or circumvent the output encoding applied to his input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `strip_tags()` this will delete all html tags

So if a `$_POST['username'] = <div style = 'color:red;font-size:30px;'>Bob</div>` than with `strip_tags($_POST['username']) = Bob`. If you also add `trim()` it will also remove leftover spaces.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

***Update***

As Joe Frambach points out, if you want to know if the username contains html use:

```
if (strip_tags($name) !== $name) { 
    echo 'this contains html'; 
} else {
    echo 'this does not contain html';
}
```

So if the stripped value is not equal to the input value it contains html.

Comment: He said *Can I detect if there is any html in the string*, not how can I clean a string

Comment: ok, then `if (strip_tags($name) !== $name) { it's invalid }`

Comment: @Joe exactly, that's the answer. You should post it

Comment: It's an obvious step from @SuperDJ's answer. I just upvoted this answer and am moving on.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I updated my answer with your comment if you don't mind

Comment: That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 4):

Validate the field is alphanumeric:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/', $input)){
    //Valid
}
else{
    //invalid
}
```

Comment: And what if a user entered his name in another language? That means also invalid? That is not a solution. It's kinda lame workaround

Comment: The field is username, not realname.

Comment: those limitations can be overcome by simply using the `\w` regex escape sequence _in php_ (JavaScript uses ASCII for `\w` and `\d` but Unicode for `\s`)